# Не работает код. Запись файла в список

Tags: c++, файлы, списки

Задача такова: нужно реализовать функцию, которая будет считывать строку с файла и записывать ее поэлементно в список. Не посимвольно, все элементы разделены пробелом. При запуске открывается консоль и почти сразу выдает уведомление о том, что прекращена работа программы.

Что может работать не так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct element
{
    string str;   //  Звездочки ставить по-разному str 
    element* next;
};

element* inputFile(string fileName) {
    string s;
    string space = " ";

    ifstream in (fileName);
    getline(in, s);
    in.close();

    element* first, *current;
    current = first = new element;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (s[i] == space[0])
            current->str = current->str + s[i];
        else
            current = current->next;

    return first;
}

int main() {
    element* list = inputFile("E:\out.txt");
    cout << list->str;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Вы не проверяете открылся ли файл и есть подозрение, что попытка работать с неоткрытым файлом приводит к проблемам.

Comment: Может потому, что надо бы `"E:\\out.txt"`, а не `"E:\out.txt"`? Кстати, приличный компилятор на это ругается, как-то так: `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\o'`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, на будущее учту про два слэша. Вся проблема оказалась в том, что я забыл выделить память для нового элемента.